# How do you return the remaining elements of a list after nth position in Racket?

Tags: list, racket

I understand the take function can return the first n elements of a list, but is there a function that returns the remaining elements?
For example:
If I have a list '(1 2 3 4 5) and I want to return a new list with the elements after the 3rd position, that would end up with a result of '(4 5).

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`drop`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._drop))) function. [`take`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) and [`drop`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._drop))) are complimentary so that `(drop lst n)` produces the rest of the list after the elemnts in `(take lst n)`.

Example:

```
> (take (list 1 2 3 4 5) 3)
(list 1 2 3)
> (drop (list 1 2 3 4 5) 3)
(list 4 5)
```

The [`drop`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._drop))) function might alternatively be called [`list-tail`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._list-tail))) in some libraries.

```
> (list-tail (list 1 2 3 4 5) 3)
(list 4 5)
```

Side note: The [`split-at`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._split-at%29%29) function returns both at the same time if you want both from one computation.

```
> (split-at (list 1 2 3 4 5) 3)
(list 1 2 3)
(list 4 5)
```

Comment: The most compatible name for `drop` is [`list-tail`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=dro%3B#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-tail%29%29)